# How to hide controls in blackberry

Tags: android, blackberry

[image]
i have three button in top just like tab and three vertical manager which have custom design. i want to hide vertical field manager when i click button(eg in android there is a property GONE and VISIBLE)  you can see in my screen.any body have idea for my problem please send.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you create vfm as

```
vfm=new VerticalFieldManager()
```

And you add it to another manager on screen like this

```
hfm.add(vfm);
```

you can remove the Vertical field manager you added earlier by doing

```
hfm.delete(vfm);
```

You can also delete all fields in a manager by calling

```
hfm.deleteAll()
```

Comment: but i want when i press again btn then is it visible once again this layout?

Comment: yes it will delete the vfm from the manager hfm. You can still retain the object and add it back if you want to

Comment: Say you have vfmanager to show yglf (young ..) or yblp. when you click on YG do vfmanager.deleteAll() ,vfmanager.add(yblpmanager). Same for others

Answer (score 2):

This is total classes when you click on Button1 first time BLUE color will disappear once again click on  Button1 BLUE color will display same as 4 buttons make some magic 
this is easy to understand how screen will invalidate and delete it's fields and re paint

```
package com.hb.screens;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BackgroundFactory;

public class DeleteVert extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener{

    private CustomButtonField btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4;
    private VerticalFieldManager vert1,vert2,vert3,vert4;
    private boolean flag1=true,flag2=true,flag3=true,flag4=true;
    public DeleteVert() {
        VerticalFieldManager main_mgr=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
            }
        };

        HorizontalFieldManager hr_mgr=new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        btn1=new CustomButtonField("BUTTON1", Color.RED);
        btn1.setChangeListener(this);
        hr_mgr.add(btn1);

        btn2=new CustomButtonField("BUTTON2", Color.RED);
        btn2.setChangeListener(this);
        hr_mgr.add(btn2);

        btn3=new CustomButtonField("BUTTON3", Color.RED);
        btn3.setChangeListener(this);
        hr_mgr.add(btn3);

        btn4=new CustomButtonField("BUTTON4", Color.RED);
        btn4.setChangeListener(this);
        hr_mgr.add(btn4);

        main_mgr.add(hr_mgr);

        vert1=new VerticalFieldManager();
        VerticalFieldManager del_mgr=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(), 70);
            }
        };
        del_mgr.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLUE));
        LabelField lbl1=new LabelField("VerticalFieldManager1");
        del_mgr.add(lbl1);
        vert1.add(del_mgr);
        main_mgr.add(vert1);


        vert2=new VerticalFieldManager();
        VerticalFieldManager del_mgr1=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(), 70);
            }
        };
        del_mgr1.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN));
        LabelField lbl2=new LabelField("VerticalFieldManager2");
        del_mgr1.add(lbl2);
        vert2.add(del_mgr1);
        main_mgr.add(vert2);

        vert3=new VerticalFieldManager();
        VerticalFieldManager del_mgr2=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(), 70);
            }
        };
        del_mgr2.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.RED));
        LabelField lbl3=new LabelField("VerticalFieldManager3");
        del_mgr2.add(lbl3);
        vert3.add(del_mgr2);
        main_mgr.add(vert3);

        vert4=new VerticalFieldManager();
        VerticalFieldManager del_mgr3=new VerticalFieldManager(){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(), 70);
            }
        };
        del_mgr3.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.CHOCOLATE));
        LabelField lbl4=new LabelField("VerticalFieldManager41");
        del_mgr3.add(lbl4);
        vert4.add(del_mgr3);
        main_mgr.add(vert4);



        add(main_mgr);


    }
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
            if(field==btn1){
                if(flag1==true){
                    flag1=false;
                    vert1.deleteAll();

                }else{
                    flag1=true;
                    VerticalFieldManager del_mgr1=new VerticalFieldManager(){
                        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                            setExtent(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                        }
                    };
                    del_mgr1.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.BLUE));
                    LabelField lbl1=new LabelField("VerticalFieldManager1");
                    del_mgr1.add(lbl1);
                    vert1.add(del_mgr1);
                }
            }else if(field==btn2){
                if(flag2==true){
                    flag2=false;
                    vert2.deleteAll();

                }else{
                    flag2=true;
                    VerticalFieldManager del_mgr2=new VerticalFieldManager(){
                        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                            setExtent(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                        }
                    };
                    del_mgr2.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN));
                    LabelField lbl2=new LabelField("VerticalFieldManager2");
                    del_mgr2.add(lbl2);
                    vert2.add(del_mgr2);
                }
            }else if(field==btn3){
                if(flag3==true){
                    flag3=false;
                    vert3.deleteAll();

                }else{
                    flag3=true;
                    VerticalFieldManager del_mgr3=new VerticalFieldManager(){
                        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                            setExtent(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                        }
                    };
                    del_mgr3.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.RED));
                    LabelField lbl3=new LabelField("VerticalFieldManager3");
                    del_mgr3.add(lbl3);
                    vert3.add(del_mgr3);
                }
            }else if(field==btn4){
                if(flag4==true){
                    flag4=false;
                    vert4.deleteAll();

                }else{
                    flag4=true;
                    VerticalFieldManager del_mgr4=new VerticalFieldManager(){
                        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                            setExtent(Display.getWidth(), 70);
                        }
                    };
                    del_mgr4.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.CHOCOLATE));
                    LabelField lbl4=new LabelField("VerticalFieldManager4");
                    del_mgr4.add(lbl4);
                    vert4.add(del_mgr4);
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

//this is customButton field this is copied from this link
[customButton [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuJPL.png)

```
package com.hb.screens;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;

public class CustomButtonField extends Field
{

    private int backgroundColour = Color.GRAY;
    private int highlightColour;
    private int fieldWidth;
    private int fieldHeight;
    private String text;
    private int padding = 8;

    public CustomButtonField(String text, int highlightColour)
    {
        super(Field.FOCUSABLE);
        this.text = text;
        this.highlightColour = highlightColour;
        Font defaultFont = Font.getDefault();
        fieldHeight = defaultFont.getHeight() + padding;
        fieldWidth = defaultFont.getAdvance(text) + (padding * 2);
        this.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
    {
        fieldChangeNotify(1);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onFocus(int direction)
    {
        backgroundColour = highlightColour;
        invalidate();
    }

    protected void onUnfocus()
    {
        backgroundColour = Color.GRAY;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth()
    {
        return fieldWidth;
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight()
    {
        return fieldHeight;
    }

    protected void layout(int arg0, int arg1)
    {
        setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
    }

    protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on)
    {

    }

    protected void fieldChangeNotify(int context)
    {
        try
        {
            this.getChangeListener().fieldChanged(this, context);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.setColor(backgroundColour);
        graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, fieldWidth, fieldHeight, 8, 8);
        graphics.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, fieldWidth, fieldHeight, 8, 8);
        graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        graphics.drawText(text, padding - 1, padding / 2 + 1);
    }
}
```

Before click on Button1]
[image: Before click on Button1]

After click on Button1]
[image: After click on Button1]

Answer (score 1):

Use delete() method.

```
private VerticalFieldManager manager = new VerticalFieldManager();
private BasicEditField bef = new BasicEditField();
manager.add(bef);
add(manager);
manager.delete(bef);
```